# CSS: Sidebar 100% height no scrolling

Tags: html, css

I want a sidebar which takes the full height of the screen and doesn't change when scrolling down.

So when I scroll only the contents changes but the navbar stays always the same.

I made a first example: http://jsfiddle.net/CwSD6/

But the none-scroll functionality is missing...

Regards

EDIT:
You need to use position: fixed, and top, bottom, left with value 0.
http://jsfiddle.net/CwSD6/1/

Comment: Already found out myself. No need for jQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/CwSD6/1/

Comment: woow great , did you check in ie ?

Comment: The `aside` element is not supported in IE7 and IE8.

Comment: I don't care about microsoft :) progress has to go

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it can be done by doing `position: fixed;` in `<aside>`

see this fiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HNjQR/)

Comment: Is it possible to dynamicly positionate the .content to the aside?
So that the content automaticly aligns to the border of aside?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
aside
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid #111;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I use the jQuery method as using fixed or absolute usually screws with my grid layout. In the example below my grid collapses when under 990px width so you would need to change this assuming you are doing responsive.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var doc_height = $(document).height();
    var doc_width = $(document).width()
    if (doc_width > 990) {
        $('#sidebar').css("height", doc_height);
    } else {
        $('#sidebar').css("height", 'auto');
    }
});
```

Although this may not be the most efficient way, you don't need to set variables. I find it helps with readability.

Kind Regards, 
M

Answer (score 0):

```
body::before {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
}

label {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
        HTML code start here 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/adminhome.css">
    <link href=”https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css” rel=”stylesheet” integrity=”sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU” crossorigin=”anonymous”>
    <link href="https://allfont.net/allfont.css?fonts=montserrat-bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" />
    <title>home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="tpe">
            <p>Admin</p>
        </div>
        <div class="headbar">
            <a href="adminallusers.html" class="allusers">
                <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                <span class="users">All Users</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="admin">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                <span class="user">Admin</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                            <span class="nav-item">Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fas fa-ticket-alt"></i>
                            <span class="nav-item">Tickets</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
                            <span class="nav-item">Upload</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fas fa-tasks"></i>
                            <span class="nav-item">Status</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="logout">
                            <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
                            <span class="nav-item">Log out</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
</body>
</html>
        
        HTML end here
        
        CSS start from here    
        
        @import url('https://allfont.net/allfont.css?fonts=montserrat-bold');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Montserrat, "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
body{
    background-color: white;
    }   
 
header{
    position: fixed;
    background:#404258;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: width 0.2s linear;
}
header .tpe p{
font-size: 28px;
font-weight:900;
float: left;
color:white;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-left:130px;
}
header a{
    position: relative;
      color: white;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 600;
      display: table;
      width: 300px;
      padding: 10px;
  }
  header:hover{
    background-color: none;
  }
.admin{
     
    padding:1px;
    background:none;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    margin-top:0px;
    width:10%;
    margin-right:-10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight:550;
    color: white;
}
.allusers{
    padding:1px;
    background:none;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    width:20%;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-right:-100px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight:550;
    color: white;
}
.user{
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    margin-right:-50px; 
    width: 250px;
}
.users{
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    margin-right:auto; 
    width: 250px;
}
nav{
    position: fixed;
    top:45px;
    bottom:-60px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background:#404258;
    width: 90px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: width 0.2s linear;
}

nav a{
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:600;
    display: table;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.fas{
    position: relative;
    width: 70px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 14px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav-item{
    position:relative;
    top:12px;
    margin-left:10px;  

}
nav a:hover{
    background: #A6ADC2;
}
nav:hover{
    width: 200px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.logout{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20;
}
        
        CSS end here
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).